# NSString to CLLocationDegrees to NSString is changing value

Tags: objective-c, json, nsstring, cllocation

I am fetching a latitude and longitude from a JSON API. These values are coming in as Strings.

I store the value in a `CLLocationDegrees` like this:

```
CLLocationDegrees lat = [[coordinates objectForKey:@"lat"] doubleValue];
CLLocationDegrees lon = [[coordinates objectForKey:@"lat"] doubleValue];
```

But when I later retrieve the values from `lat` and `lon` and put them into an `NSString`, the value has changed from what was provided by the JSON. The change is usually only the last few digits of the coordinate, but it is enough to cause a problem.

```
NSString *latitude = [[NSNumber numberWithDouble:lat] stringValue];
NSString *longitude = [[NSNumber numberWithDouble:lon] stringValue];
```

Basically, at this point, `[coordinates objectForKey:@"lat"]` is not equal to `latitude`.

Any tips about how to fix this would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NSNumber stringValue` is going to give you a default representation which generally only has 5 decimal places.

One option would to use `stringWithFormat` and use a format that matches the data you have from the original JSON.

```
NSString *latitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.7f", lat];
```

Adjust the format specifier to meet your exact needs.

Also keep in mind that going from the original string to a `double` could result in some loss of precision due to the nature of how floating point numbers are represented. There's nothing you can do about that except keep a reference to the original string if it is that important.

Comment: I should have said this in the original post, but it's not that I'm losing precision... the digits are the same length but are changing. For instance, one went from `40.78399658203125` to `40.7839965820328` ... the 5 at the end changed to an 8. Is this still a result of the same formatting situation?

Comment: `double` is good to about 15 significant digits. The number `40.78399658203125` has 16 significant digits. So you can expect some loss. And even if there isn't loss due to the number of digits, you can see apparent loss due to the inability to represent all possible values in a floating point type like `double`.